# Method width() is undefined for the type Rectangle

Tags: java, awt

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class IONS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle x = new Rectangle(10, 20);
        int width = x.width();
        System.out.println(width);
    }
}
```

There is an error in line 7 while compiling, where am I going wrong?

```
ERROR: The method width() is undefined for the type Rectangle   IONS.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `.getWidth()` (and expect a `double`!) or just use `.width` (retrieving the width directly from your rectangle).

There is no method `.width()`.